# Oracle date issues

Tags: oracle

Once more, I'm encountering issues converting a date string into a date to store in the database. The string is being read from a csv file, and loaded into a DATE column.

```
SELECT TO_DATE('23-NOV-16 06.21.20.431000 PM', 'DD-MMM-YY HH.MI.SS.FF PM') 
FROM dual;
```

I have had zero success finding the correct format that allows this to be read into the database.

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: Found my mistake. Somehow I was thinking MMM, rather than MON. I re-read of the documentation fixed me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not MMM, it supposed to be MON

In such scenario I will give small string first for conversion i.e. date, if its working then time, time fractional so can narrow down problem area.